# Get JSON response and insert into table cells based on specific key in JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

Below is my JSON response from server

```
[  
{  
  "id":"32df40f8-44a8-11e9-abcd-005056a92189",
  "filename":"BHR.PNG",
  "name":"Qatar",
  "step_c":"1",
  "date_uploaded":"2019-03-12"
},
{  
  "id":"693e2cb4-40a6-11e9-9754-005056a92189",
  "filename":"CT2.PNG",
  "name":"Qatar",
  "step_c":"1",
  "date_uploaded":"2019-03-07"
},
{  
  "id":"87d29f34-40a6-11e9-b03a-005056a92189",
  "filename":"CT3.PNG",
  "name":"Qatar",
  "step_c":"2",
  "date_uploaded":"2019-03-07"
}
]
```

Part of my jQuery code below

```
if(json != null && json.length > 0)
{      
$.each(json, function(index, value) {
if(this.step_c == 1){
   $("#s1").html("<a href='https://example.com/rest/v10/DocumentLinks/" + this.id + "/file/uploadfile?force_download=1&platform=base'>" + this.filename + "</a>");
   $("#u1").html(this.date_uploaded);
}
if(this.step_c == 2){
   $("#s2").html("<a href='https://example.com/rest/v10/DocumentLinks/" + this.id + "/file/uploadfile?force_download=1&platform=base'>" + this.filename + "</a>");
   $("#u2").html(this.date_uploaded);
}
});
}
```

Here I am trying to get the data from JSON response and insert it into my html table cells. s1, u1 are table tds.

What I need to do here is when the step_c is 1, I want to get all filenames and insert into td with comma separated. Here when step_c is 1 there are two filenames BHR.PNG and CT2.PNG, so I want to get both filenames and insert them to #s1 as BHR.PNG, CT2.PNG.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice and simple this one.

Replace:

```
$("#s1").html("<a href='https://example.com/rest/v10/DocumentLinks/" + this.id + "/file/uploadfile?force_download=1&platform=base'>" + this.filename + "</a>");
```

With:

```
    var fileLabel = this.filename;
    if (index > 0) {
      fileLabel = ", " + this.filename; 
    }
    $("#s1").append("<a href='https://example.com/rest/v10/DocumentLinks/" + this.id + "/file/uploadfile?force_download=1&platform=base'>" + fileLabel + "</a>");
```

You're looking for "append" not "html". You could also tweak the fileLabel variable to not include a comma within the A tag but this is a good place to start.

Comment: I think you understood it in other way or I may didn't explained it properly. Actually for each filename there is separate id too. So, A tag should repeat multiple times with respect to filenames and ids.

Comment: The A tag does repeat multiple times with different names + ids?